# select one row and some row in second table

Tags: mysql

i've 2 tables 1st named `orders` and 2nd named `rewinding`.

1st `orders` has one record

```
id=1, job_code=597, job_name=xyz
```

2nd `rewinding` has one or more than one record

```
id=5, job_code=597, weight=254,remarks=foo
id=6, job_code=600, weight=765,remarks=foo
id=7, job_code=597, weight=594,remarks=foo
id=8, job_code=597, weight=54,remarks=foo
```

Now I want to select all the `rows and columns` which has `code=597` and only record from `orders where job_code=597`

Comment: @Syed : its a simple JOIN stuff....if you would google it, you'll get it easily!! :)

Comment: i didn't try anything yet i'm getting confuse how to select

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What about this?

```
SELECT *, orders.id orders_id, rewinding.id rewinding_id 
FROM orders
JOIN rewinding ON orders.job_code = rewinding.job_code
WHERE orders.job_code = 597
```

Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b1ad6/4

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple rows in `orders` with the `job_code` and you only want one, then use `limit` in a subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT o.* FROM orders o WHERE o.job_code = 597 LIMIT 1
     ) as o597 JOIN
     rewinding r
    ON o597.job_code = r.job_code;
```